# Flutter get User Data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to get User Data from firebase, I need the `diplayName` of a User. is there any way to get the `displayName` of a other user with his `uid`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to look up information about another user in Firebase Authentication by using the client-side SDKs of Firebase, as that would be a security risk.

There are two common ways  to allow searching the users in a secure way:

- Write information about each user to a database (such as Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database) when they register, and then search the database when needed. That way your code controls what data gets written and thus is searchable.
- Firebase has Admin SDKs that run in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. These SDKs have options to list users, which means you can search them. If you wrap one of the Admin SDKs in a custom API that you build and secure yourself, you can then call that from your Flutter code.

Also see:

- [React native firebase authentication searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605560/react-native-firebase-authentication-searching/62605948#62605948)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the name, or any other details of a user that is not currently signed in using FirebaseAuth.

Instead, you must create a node in your database where you store the name, and any other necessary details by querying the database.